# Docker Compose file does not create postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgresql-16

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: my_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

The log from the new container:

```
2023-11-19 14:28:02 The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
2023-11-19 14:28:02 This user must also own the server process.
2023-11-19 14:28:02 
2023-11-19 14:28:02 The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
2023-11-19 14:28:02 The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
2023-11-19 14:28:02 The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
2023-11-19 14:28:02 
2023-11-19 14:28:02 Data page checksums are disabled.
2023-11-19 14:28:02 
2023-11-19 14:28:02 fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
2023-11-19 14:28:02 creating subdirectories ... ok
2023-11-19 14:28:02 selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
2023-11-19 14:28:02 selecting default max_connections ... 100
2023-11-19 14:28:02 selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
2023-11-19 14:28:02 selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
2023-11-19 14:28:02 creating configuration files ... ok
2023-11-19 14:28:02 running bootstrap script ... ok
2023-11-19 14:28:02 performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
2023-11-19 14:28:02 syncing data to disk ... ok
2023-11-19 14:28:02 
2023-11-19 14:28:02 
2023-11-19 14:28:02 Success. You can now start the database server using:
2023-11-19 14:28:02 
2023-11-19 14:28:02     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
2023-11-19 14:28:02 
2023-11-19 14:28:02 waiting for server to start....2023-11-19 17:28:02.849 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2023-11-19 14:28:02 2023-11-19 17:28:02.852 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-11-19 14:28:02 2023-11-19 17:28:02.861 UTC [51] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-11-19 17:28:02 UTC
2023-11-19 14:28:02 2023-11-19 17:28:02.866 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-11-19 14:28:02  done
2023-11-19 14:28:02 server started
2023-11-19 14:28:03 CREATE DATABASE
2023-11-19 14:28:03 
2023-11-19 14:28:03 
2023-11-19 14:28:03 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
2023-11-19 14:28:03 
2023-11-19 14:28:03 waiting for server to shut down...2023-11-19 17:28:03.028 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-11-19 14:28:03 .2023-11-19 17:28:03.030 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-11-19 14:28:03 2023-11-19 17:28:03.031 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54) exited with exit code 1
2023-11-19 14:28:03 2023-11-19 17:28:03.032 UTC [49] LOG:  shutting down
2023-11-19 14:28:03 2023-11-19 17:28:03.033 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-11-19 14:28:03 2023-11-19 17:28:03.102 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 923 buffers (5.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.014 s, sync=0.051 s, total=0.071 s; sync files=301, longest=0.010 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4257 kB, estimate=4257 kB; lsn=0/1913068, redo lsn=0/1913068
2023-11-19 14:28:03 2023-11-19 17:28:03.108 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-11-19 14:28:03  done
2023-11-19 14:28:03 server stopped
2023-11-19 14:28:03 
2023-11-19 14:28:03 PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
2023-11-19 14:28:03 
2023-11-19 14:28:02 initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
2023-11-19 14:28:02 initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
2023-11-19 14:28:03 2023-11-19 17:28:03.146 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2023-11-19 14:28:03 2023-11-19 17:28:03.146 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-11-19 14:28:03 2023-11-19 17:28:03.146 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-11-19 14:28:03 2023-11-19 17:28:03.149 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-11-19 14:28:03 2023-11-19 17:28:03.153 UTC [64] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-11-19 17:28:03 UTC
2023-11-19 14:28:03 2023-11-19 17:28:03.158 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

The issue is that I can't connect to the created database, and it doesn't show up when connecting through Heidi or Beekeeper, apart from the schemas "information_schema", "pg_catalog", "pg_toast" and "public".

I've tried several different approaches, including creating an init_db.sh file to create the database "my_db", but haven't been able to make it work.

I've made sure to remove all postgres_data volumes and containers, but my_db is never created, nor is any postgres database.

I have also tried not setting up the POSTGRES_USER and/or POSTGRES_DB, but a database simply isn't created.

One last thing I have attempted was to delete the postgres image, no success either.

I have also tried different postgres and docker versions

EDIT: I have now confirmed that the database somehow exists, as I try to run the sql command `CREATE DATABASE my_db` gives me an error `ERROR: database "my_db" already exists`, which leads me to think that I'm misunderstanding something. By all means, I still cannot connect to it nor see it no matter what.

Comment: `information_schema`, `pg_catalog`, `pg_toast` and `public` **are not databases**. Each is a `schema` within a database and are the only ones created during `create database`. if you need additional then see the documentation for [Create Schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createschema.html).

Comment: @Belayer thanks for the correction, but what I want is not a schema and really a new database, what I meant is that those are the 'databases' that SQL Managers such as HeidiSQL and Beekeeper displays to me.

Comment: If those tools call those things databases, then they are using the word wrong.  If they won't give you accurate information, then stop relying on them to give you accurate information.

Comment: @jjanes What do you use or recommend?

Comment: I usually use psql (the command line interface that comes with postgresql) but for a GUI prefer  dbeaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the reason the database my_db doesn't show up is because I don't have a clue on how to connect to them correctly through Heidi and Beekeeper, because it displays fine when using DBeaver instead.

[dbeaver table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD6yK.png)

And I couldn't connect to it before because I had required SSL_MODE in my backend.